# How to avoid duplicate records when update in DB using hibernate

Tags: java, database, hibernate, java-ee-6, hibernate-mapping

I am updating the record with multiple entries in the db at a time.when i try to create another multiple records, duplicate entries are saved in DB.how to prevent records from duplicates entry using hibernate.i want to restrict 2 or more column value should not equal as before

Comment: What about the relative code ??

Comment: Do you have your insert methods synchronized?

Comment: @sureshatta for one market id, i m creating 4 entries per month like 1/08/2013 to 31/08/2013.when i select same market id with other dates like 15/08/2013 to 18/09/2013 duplicates entries are allowed from the previous entry

Comment: @JunedAhsan no insert methods not synchronized

Comment: before inserting entries you can check their uniqueness by using `Map` with the existing entries in dataBase

Comment: Did you consider constructing composite primary key with unique columns for your table?

Answer (score 1):

Defining a primary key, or at least a unique constraint, on the table, is the surest way to avoid duplicates. Then your code will throw some useful errors for you to handle transactions properly.

Answer (score 1):

Define your entity object with Unique Constraints

```
    @Entity
    @Table(name="user_group", 
              uniqueConstraints = {@UniqueConstraint(columnNames = {"user_id", "group_id"})})
    public class UserGroup implements Serializable
    {

         User user //This is user model
         Group group // This is Group model 
             // Other fields
             // setter and getter methods.

    }
```

Save the objects within a transaction

```
 Session session = sessionFactory().openSession();
 session.beginTransaction();
 session.saveOrUpdate(listOfuserGroup);
 session.getTransaction().commit();
```

Comment: my primary key ids are unique...data what i am inserting in db is same except id, and marketcode.i tried using uniqueconstraint..but no luck